# Facing a strange memory "leak" with Java 1.6

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I'm trying to understand where is used server memory.
When I look to the memory usage on the system via top I've got :

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 6091 oper      20   0 2721m 1.4g 9180 S    0 11.4   6:13.42 java
10854 oper      20   0 2186m 1.1g 5104 S    1  9.1 114:52.15 java
 9350 oper      20   0 2293m 971m 4892 S    0  8.0  40:15.68 java
 9286 oper      20   0 2082m 800m 4852 S    0  6.6  31:31.44 java
10506 oper      20   0 1936m 711m 4900 S    0  5.9  49:09.64 java
 8965 oper      20   0 1918m 680m 5076 S    0  5.6 106:53.10 java
```

All those process are tomcats 6.0.20 running on JVM 1.6.0_26

As we can see in the top report, one process is using 1.4GO an other 1.1GO... so much more than expected.
When I open JConsole on the first process I can see cumulated memory (the Heap and non heap memory) is arround 200Mo, on the second 385 Mo, the third 235Mo.

So my question is where is the unvisible memory ?

```
Top - JConsole = 
1.4G - 200M    = 1.2G
1.1G - 385M    = 715M
971M - 235M    = 736M
800M - 173M    = 627M
```

Does any one have an idea ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Total resident memory includes all the perm space, the JARs mapped in for the server, lots of other stuff.

Comment: what is this, gigaoyte?

Comment: Also, once Java (or any other program) obtains memory from the system, it generally does not give it back until the process exits.  The memory may be available for reuse by the process, but its overall memory reservation does not normally shrink.  Moreover, if you allow Java a large maximum heap size, then it may choose to use that whole size to (initially) limit the amount of garbage collection needed.

Comment: Yes G or g is GigaByte M or m is MegaByte.

Comment: May be I'm wrong but I thougt that the amount of memory used by the JVM is visible as the Commited memory. I my case commited memory is low. I suppose java has other memory regions, and the huge amount of unvisible memory is in one of those regions, but I don't know how I can diagnose it !

Comment: Sorry Thomas, I just realised why you asked this question. GO is GigaOctet in french equivalent to GB GigaByte.